# How to get the Synaptics PS/2 driver to work properly over a USB connection

Tags: usb, mouse, synaptics-touchpad, ps2

I have a physical disability that makes it impossible to use a computer normally, and the only thing that works for me is the Synaptics Touchstyk mouse, which is similar to trackpoint. It only comes on certain laptop models, and I'm having trouble finding one that meets my needs, plus they're usually the more expensive business models. So I want to remove it from a laptop so I can use it on any computer.

Anyway, I have the pinout for the ribbon cable that attaches to the motherboard as well as followed [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/XdznW0ZuzGo). The interface is PS/2. So I could make a PCB that converts it to a PS/2 connector, and I've done enough experimenting to know that will work, and then I used a USB adapter.

That works, but the Synaptics driver uses some proprietary PS/2 protocol which gives it more detailed data on the force applied to the sensor, which allows it to be it much more sensitive. So while this PS/2 to USB setup works, I need that high level of sensitivity and am unsure how to achieve that.

I don't think I can just use the Synaptics driver on the USB to PS/2 adapter, it needs to interface with the raw PS/2 protocol. Is there some other way? Is there a USB to PS/2 adapter that looks like a PS/2 port to the computer? Or some way for the driver to work over USB?

Thanks for any ideas, or where would be a better place to ask this question.

Comment: “That works, but the Synaptics driver uses some proprietary PS/2 protocol which gives it more detailed data on the force applied to the sensor, which allows it to be it much more sensitive. I need that high level of sensitivity.” So you mean you can get it to work over USB, but the specific high-sensitivity data you need was not being transferred, thus the mouse is working technically but not as well as it could?

Comment: Basically, yes.

Comment: And do you have a link or reference to the pinouts and such that allowed you to get it working externally?

Comment: yeah. I have some of the documentation and from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XdznW0ZuzGo&ab_channel=LenkaDesignWorkshop.

Comment: Good to know. This is definitely the right place to ask the question. In my mind though, I believe the solution might be in some general / all purpose HID driver that would be smart enough to be able to adjust sensitivity here. I mean, unless this device is truly proprietary in nature, my assumption would be the sensitivity is somehow detected by a generic device. And the drivers for the PS/2 stuff just grab that data. But honestly, this seems tough. I almost think a more customizing focused forum would work. But no reason this can’t exist here too. Wish you luck in solving this!

Comment: You would think so, but the standard PS/2 mode sends less data, for example the proprietary mode provides the downward pressure on the stick, and the other data is higher resolution raw data.